Why ToJson saves only {}?
Before this, I saved only one instance of the class in Json, and everything worked. Now when I try to save the whole array, nothing works for me. Please don't advise me to switch to some Newtonsoft. Everywhere they say that JsonUtility can save arrays. Tell me, maybe there is an error in my script?
Here is code:
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;

public class JsonSaveSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> obj;

    [SerializeField] private Inventory[] objs;
    [SerializeField] private List<possave> pos;
    private string path;
    possave ps;
    void Start()
    {
        while(obj.Count > pos.Count)
        {
            pos.Add(ps);
        }
        path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "data.json");
        Load();
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        //Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(pos[0]));
        if(obj.Count > pos.Count)
        {
            
            pos.Add(ps);
        }
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        if(File.Exists(path))
        {
            pos = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<possave>>(File.ReadAllText(path));
            for(int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < obj.Count; k++)
                {
                    if(objs[i].ID == pos[k].ID)
                    {
                        Destroy(obj[k]);
                        obj[k] = Instantiate(objs[i].obj, new Vector3(pos[k].x, pos[k].y, pos[k].z), Quaternion.identity);                                  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create(path);
        }
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++)
        {
            pos[i].x = obj[i].transform.position.x;
            pos[i].y = obj[i].transform.position.y;
            pos[i].z = obj[i].transform.position.z;
            pos[i].ID = obj[i].GetComponent<Takeobjectec>().obj.ID;
            File.WriteAllText(path, JsonUtility.ToJson(pos));
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class possave
{
    public float x, y, z;
    public string ID;
}

I tried to save everything using JsonSerializer, but Unity gave me the error: error CS0122: 'JsonSerializer' is inaccessible due to its protection level. I wrote using System.Text.Json at the beginning of the script, so that wasn't the issue. If JsonSerializer needs something else, and this is the only way to save an array, please tell me what it needs.

JsonUtility can save arrays but only as object fields. In other words you can serialize { "foo": [1, 2, 3] } but can't serialize [1, 2, 3] alone.

How can I change the script to make it work?

Either use something else other than JsonUtility, or make a serializable class that has a list field and serialize that, the same way you've made the possave class

Take a look at this answer by Programmer to Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity. specifically 2. MULTIPLE DATA(ARRAY JSON): Unity's JsonUtility does not support array as it is still new but you can use a helper class from this person to get array working with JsonUtility.  You can also use Json.NET as it is now officially supported.  Add com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json via the package manager.  Does that answer your question?
